# Question about GRE sentence in supporting the passage?

Tags: reading, gre

I am confused about the this solution. It says that the author includes "East End working-class theaters" to illustrate that the magazines can sway public opinion.

Although the preceding sentence discusses this, how can we know that the working class had a favorable opinion of "East End theaters," thus confirming that their opinions were swayed? The passage never addresses the actual working-class's opinion.

The only possible explanation is that if this sentence was not supporting the idea that magazines could sway public opinion, then it would be a useless/irrelevant sentence. Is this enough justification to support this answer, or is there another explanation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key is in the sentence:

> The role of magazines of **arbiters** of nineteenth-century taste is seen in their depiction of the London theatre.

Magazines being [**arbiters**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arbiter) here means that they are:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> a person or agency whose judgment or opinion is considered authoritative · *arbiters* of taste

In other words, the magazines are the authority on what public opinion should be. As the authority, they "determine" or "sway" public opinion.

While the interpretation on its own could easily be argued as not necessarily true (you could debate the premise), it's the most reasonable interpretation from among the five possible answers that are presented. (By the process of elimination, the other four answers are either completely unsupported by the passage or are are simply less reasonable.)

You're not supposed to necessarily *agree* with the one interpretation, but choose it as "better than" the others.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. The answer choice says that they are supporting that the magazines are the arbiters. We aren't taking for an immediate fact that the magazines are definitely arbiters. Without knowing what the working-class thought, the bolded statement doesn't support anything

Comment: Right. The exercise is about reading comprehension and summarizing the passage. Based on that, the exercise *does* have you take for a fact that they are arbiters. (Because that's what it says.) You are supposed to determine which of the answers best fits the passage as given, not come up with your own interpretation.

Comment: Ok, assuming that they are indeed arbiters, I don't understand how the bolded sentence is meant to "illustrate a point." It's more like, giving an example of how they influenced public opinion rather than support the fact that they did influence public opinion

Comment: @Goldname: Your last sentence is correct.  It is an example of how they influenced public opinion.  Replace "example" with its near-synonym "illustration" and the offered answer then matches nicely.

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually, my wording is incorrect. they are not "giving an example" at all, because we don't even know the opinions of the middle-class! So, they are basically saying half a statement, not providing an example and hence not supporting their argument

Comment: If instead they said "accorded some legitimacy to... which is why the working-class finds theaters fashionable" it would support their point, but they never even state the latter

Comment: @Goldname What the passage is saying is that the magazine accorded working-class theatre some legitimacy by publishing accounts of those venues (in the East End) alongside accounts of middle- and upper-class theatres (in the West End). *Because* the magazine was that "arbiter" of taste, it served to elevate the public opinion of the East End theatres.

Comment: The problem here is circular logic. You are saying that this statement supports the argument because the argument is already true. That doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: @Goldname There is nothing circular. This is a reading comprehension test. Everything in the passage is to be taken as the truth. It's not open to debate. Nor are you to provide your *own* interpretation of any of the events. Instead, all you can do is choose from the interpretations given.